# How to remove content between two tags on several files

Tags: plugins

i want to know how to delete all the content between two tags on several files.

Example:
I have 3 files that have the `<head>` and `</head>` tags, but they have different content on them, so i want to remove all the content between that two tags with some kind of tool, plugin, etc.

Is there any program, application or plugin that can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: You could use Notepad++'s Search/Replace, it can perform a replace on all open documents.

Comment: But search/replace only works with the same content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In Notepad++**

Use RegExp search and

search for

```
<head>[^<>]+</head>
```

replace all with

```
<head></head>
```

As [@domdom mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44964396/how-to-remove-content-between-two-tags-on-several-files/44964501#comment76903664_44964396), you can search through all opened documents.